# Simple drawing on NSView

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drawing

I am working on simple drawing application. After looking around, I see many people using drawRect for a lot of different things. At this point of my project, all I really need is the simplest way to draw one black pixel or dot at a given point on an NSView.

Similarly to click on the NSView and a Point is drawn there.

Thanks all!

Comment: Show us the code you're working with so we can see what you're doing and offer some advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple provides quite a lot of documentation that explains [how to draw in a view](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/2ddrawing/conceptual/drawingprintingios/graphicsdrawingoverview/graphicsdrawingoverview.html). To answer your specific question, if you're going to draw in a view, you should do it in `-drawRect:`. UIBezierPath is a good way to get started. To draw a dot, just draw a line that's 1px thick and 1px long.

Comment: Since the question was about NSView and not UIView, here's the correct link for macOS: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CocoaViewsGuide/SubclassingNSView/SubclassingNSView.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40002978-CH7-SW22